# Conduction and propagation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electricity, waves, wavefunction

What is the difference between conduction of electric wave in conductor and propagation of electromagnetic wave in dielectric?

Why propagation term is used for dielectric and conduction for conductor?.

Somehow why propagation of electromagnetic wave (is it energy wave) is not possible in conductor, but in dielectrics, and conduction (power signal) not possible in dielectric.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does electricity propagate in a conductor?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17741/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as “conduction of electric *wave* in conductor” (and I am unsure about where “electric waves” can be observed). There is a conduction of electric *current* in a conductor. One can say that electric potential in a piece of conductor is always the same (so the electric field is zero inside it), although it is not always so due to resistance, and generally the concept of electric potential is rather foggy; see [Ambiguity on the notion of potential in electrical circuits?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129404/ambiguity-on-the-notion-of-potential-in-electrical-circuits) for discussion. An electric wire or other device made of conductor can [guide a wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_%28electromagnetism%29), but such wave can propagate only due to presence of a dielectric (vacuum included). Thick shields made of a conductor, instead, are used to completely suppress (reflect and partially absorb) incoming E/M radiation in an appropriate frequency range.

In a (non-vacuum) dielectric, *both* electric and magnetic fields can exist, so an **electromagnetic** wave can propagate, although not exactly in the same way as in vacuum due to effects of permeability (electric, and possibly magnetic).