# DC circuit- parallel vs short circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, short-circuits

In a DC circuit, imagine a resistance of 10 Ohms connected parallel to a resistance of 20 Ohms, which is also parallel to a battery of V volts. In such a case, current will be distributed to the two of them.

However, in a short circuit, no current would pass through the resistance. Why does this happen? If the path of electrons is obstructed by the accumulation of electrons at the resistance, shouldn't the same happen in the above case as well?

Comment: Have you taken any basic electricity courses?

Comment: You've already asked essentially the same question here more than once: [is this the reason why current doesn't flow over a resistance if there is another path without resistance? (duplicate)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438866/9887)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that no current pass through a resistor which has a short-circuit accros its terminals is wrong.

In a realistic circuit, a short-circuit has a non-zero resistance. In that case, the current flowing to each branch depends on the current capacity of the source.
If your source can supply enough current to the short-circuit and the resistor, then both will get the same current as if the other was not there.
Otherwise, both branches will get less current than if the other was not there, but the short-circuit will get way more current than the resistor ([KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law) will tell you how much).

Comment: I think the OP was referring to the parallel resistance, not the short-circuit. You might ask for clarification

Comment: @BobD Are you talking about my last sentence? If yes, I did not mean to talk only about the short citcuit, I just meant that it will get more current than the resistor and that using KCL one can calculate the current both in the short circuit and in the resistor. Please feel free to edit the answer as I think it's clear in that regard, but it seems it is not.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the first sentence. I thought the term "resistance" referred to the parallel 10/20 ohm resistance.

Answer (score -1):

> no current would pass through the resistance. Why does this happen?

The answer from an ideal circuit theory perspective is as follows:

By definition, the voltage across a short-circuit is *zero* regardless of the current through.

By definition, parallel connected circuit elements have *identical* voltage across. Thus, a resistor in parallel with a short-circuit has zero volts across.

Finally, by Ohm's law, the current through a resistor with resistance $R \gt 0\,\Omega$ and with zero volts across is zero.