# How can electrons realize that there is a path of zero resistance to move?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrons, electrical-resistance

[image: Short Circuit]

In this situation if we apply voltage across the terminals of the circuit, we will see that no current passes through the resistances R1, R2, R3 rather *all the current passes through the wire of zero resistance* (i.e. short circuit). My question is: **Why does the current pass through the wire of zero resistance, i.e. how can the electrons realize that there is a path for moving which has zero resistance ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't current pass through a resistance if there is another path without resistance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437355/)

Comment: Duplicates of this question likely have been asked and closed many times because it's a common misunderstanding based on litteral (or anthropological) interpretation of common figurative terms (like, electrons "choose" the path of least resistance). If the question linked is not enough, I'm sure a quick search would indeed answer it.